# Strange battery levels

Tags: battery

Does this look right at all?  With only 2 and 5 cycle counts, shouldn't `ENERGY_FULL` be the same as `ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN` ?  These batteries are brand new, and they never seem to charge all the way.

```
[~]$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT{0..1}/uevent     
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Unknown
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=2
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11400000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=12685000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=0
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=23480000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=22170000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=22100000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=99
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=45N1113
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=LGC
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=  607

POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT1
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Unknown
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=5
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11400000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=12754000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=0
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=23480000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=23020000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=22510000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=97
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=45N1127
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=LGC
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER= 1977
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most detrimental factors to battery service life is overcharging.
Old battery chargers were set to a voltage just above the batteries max voltage to ensure fully charging. That is why it used to be advised to remove the battery if primarily on A/C power.

To maximize battery service life, smart charger and smart battery technology was developed. The smart chip in the battery tells the charger how fast to charge it and when to stop charging: ie the battery throttles the charger, 
and turns off the charger before reaching max designed charge. Thus, preventing overcharging.

energy full design is the maximum designed charge.
energy full  is the point where the battery turns of the charger.